# How to uninstall Atom on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, atom

I am looking for a way to uninstall Atom on Ubuntu 17.10. Is there any script for it? I want to completely uninstall Atom from my machine.

Comment: It depends on the way you installed it. If you used another way, not mentioned in the current answers, please [edit] your question accordingly!

Comment: Sudo apt remove atom.

Comment: Might work.....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To completely remove a package:

```
sudo apt purge <package_name>
```

In your case:

```
sudo apt purge atom
```

But if Atom was installed from `snap`? You have to remove it by `snap`. From the command line run this:

```
snap remove atom
```

Comment: What if you don't remember how you installed it? I guess you can try both but is there an easy way to check first?

Comment: @BrianC You can run `snap list` and look for Atom in the output. If it's there, that means that it's installed with `snap`. If not, it's installed using `apt`/`apt-get`.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy! If you have installed using `snap`, then run:

```
sudo snap remove atom
```

Else, using `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get remove atom
```

After this remove the dependencies using:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Done!